# Spring Integration queue is not getting message but channel is getting

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-integration, spring-jms

Using Spring Integration for transferring message from one queue to other in Websphere MQ.

OutPut Channel shows message is going but I am not able to see in Queue from MQ Explorer.How the session commits ? and I am not able to stop the java application. How to gracefully stop with connection stop ? 
where I am doing wrong ?
Here is the context config -

```
<int:logging-channel-adapter log-full-message="true" id="logger" level="INFO"/>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="1414" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="TEST" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="inQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="TESTQ" />
</bean>
<bean id="outQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="DEST_QUEUE" />
</bean>
<int:channel id="readFromChannel">
 <int:interceptors>
  <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
</int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="sendToChannel" >
    <int:queue/>
<int:interceptors>
  <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
</int:interceptors> 
</int:channel>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsInAdapter"
connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory"
destination="inQueue"
channel="readFromChannel" />

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsOutAdapter"
connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory"
destination="outQueue"
channel="sendToChannel" />


<bean id="myMessenger" class="test.MyMessenger" />     

<int:service-activator id="servAct" input-channel="readFromChannel" output-channel="sendToChannel" ref="myMessenger" method="transfer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use-case correctly, you want to shift messages from `TESTQ` to `DEST_QUEUE`. But you have `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` for both to read messages from them, but no one to put messages to `DEST_QUEUE`.

Your `<int:service-activator>` get message from `readFromChannel` and it means 'get message from `TESTQ`', but it places message to the `sendToChannel`. But it doesn't say that you place a message to the `DEST_QUEUE`.

That is because `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` is for reading messages from JMS (MQ in your case).

To send message to JMS (to the `DEST_QUEUE` in your case) you have to use `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` and there is no reason to mark `sendToChannel` as `<queue>`

Comment: thanks I will try with the <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

Comment: Thanks Artem It worked thanks very much ... Can you tell in this How to stop the application after it read 1000 messages.

Comment: I have in my MyMessenger class : if(count == 3) {
               
               MessageChannel inChannel = (MessageChannel) TestJMS.context.getBean("readFromChannel");
            Message<String> operation = (Message<String>)MessageBuilder.withPayload("@servAct.stop()").build();
            inChannel.send(operation);
              }

Comment: But this stops the channel not the application connections .

Comment: Right, because you stop `service-activator`, but you really have to stop the JMS consumer. In your case it is a `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` for `TESTQ`.

Comment: thanks for helping  ... I tried with this - Message<String> operation = (Message<String>)MessageBuilder.withPayload("@jmsInAdapter.stop()").build();
            inChannel.send(operation);  --------------- But it did not work ... I want to stop the connection and close everything.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you send stop command to the `readFromChannel`: for this purpose there is out of th box component - Control Bus: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus. From other side, if you want 'to close' everything you should just stop your application.

Comment: ok - so if I stop the application then all the connections will gracefully close ...